# In R function ggplotly ( from plotly package), how to adjust the label content

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

When I use function ggplotly (from plotly package), how to change the pop label content (**remove the label content in the red rectangular in attached image**)?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
mdate <- c(44197,44198,44199,44200,44201,44202,44203,44204,44205,44206,44207,44208,44209,44210,44211,44212,44213,44214,44215,44216,44217,44218,44219,44220,44197,44198,44199,44200,44201,44202,44203,44204,44205,44206,44207,44208,44209,44210,44211,44212,44213,44214,44215,44216,44217,44218,44219,44220)
myear <- c(2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020)
amount <- c(45,2,2,87,93,32,31,42,84,93,24,13,12,48,39,33,88,78,15,6,51,55,32,93,14,16,11,84,47,87,40,45,57,76,24,91,11,96,44,82,99,17,75,59,22,89,61,93)

p <- data.frame(mdate,myear,amount) %>% 
  mutate(mdata=as.Date(mdate),
         myear=as.factor(myear)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=as.Date(mdate),y=amount,color=myear))+geom_line()+
  theme_minimal()

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to edit the default tooltip?

Comment: @AnilGoyal  right, that's what i want .Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can pass specifications for the tooltip (i.e. which values to use) to plotly:

```
p <- data.frame(mdate,myear,amount) %>% 
  mutate(mdata=as.Date(mdate, origin ="1904-01-01"),
         myear=as.factor(myear)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mdata, y=amount, color=myear)) +
  geom_line()+
  theme_minimal() 

ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("y", "colour"))
```

[image]

P.S. While ggplot2 does allow both spellings "color" and "colour" plotly seems to insist on "colour"...

Comment: thanks for your help, it's great!

Comment: I meet a additional question: Is there way to chang the fill color and board color for ggplotly tooltip ? Could you help on this, Thanks !